# How do I stop eclipse from auto removing all spacing between my methods?

Tags: java, eclipse, format, whitespace, autoformatting

It only happens once in a while, but I'll look down and suddenly [all of my methods are right on top of one another, with no spacing between.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpPxg.png)  The example in Preferences --> Java --> Code Style --> Formatter looks as it should (default), with the proper spacing. However, Eclipse continues to do this anyway. How do I prevent it from happening?

Note: I am new to all this, but am confident I have properly exhausted my search for sufficiently similar questions.

Comment: The display of those methods is collapsed (there is a + at the left and notice the gaps in the line numbers). Click the + to expand

Comment: The collapsing is not the issue, it's the fact that the spaces between the methods were removed. I collapsed them for the screenshot so it would be easy to tell, but if I expanded them there would still be no spaces between the methods.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ctrl+a
2. Ctrl+Shift+f
   this will automatically space your code and it will look pretty. This is called indentation Ctrl + I might also work.
   If this is not what you want then pls tell that what are you expecting.

Comment: Thank you. That worked as an individual measure. But is there some option in Eclipse to force it to leave the spacing between my methods alone for good, so I don't have to worry about it again?

Comment: I am afraid that does not happen just press Ctrl + I whenever you feel your code is being clumsy.

Comment: Another option is to go to Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->SaveActions and check the Format source code option. Then your source code will be formatted truly automatically each time you save it.